# Need clarification on Sort by Frequency of second element in Tuple List program

Tags: python

```
from collections import Counter

test_list = [(6, 5), (2, 7), (2, 5), (8, 7), (9, 8), (3, 7)]

freq_2ndEle=Counter(val for key,val in test_list)

res=sorted(test_list,key=lambda ele:freq_2ndEle[ele[1]],reverse=True)

print(res)
```

- Input : `test_list = [(6, 5), (1, 7), (2, 5), (8, 7), (9, 8), (3, 7)]`
- Output : `[(1, 7), (8, 7), (3, 7), (6, 5), (2, 5), (9, 8)]`
- Explanation : 7 occurs 3 times as 2nd element, hence all tuples with 7, are aligned first.

please clarify how the code is working especially, this part

```
res=sorted(test_list,key=lambda ele:freq_2ndEle[ele[1]],reverse=True)
```

I have confusion on  `ele:freq_2ndEle[ele[1]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an explanation - in the future, you should try following similar steps, including reading the documentation:

- [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) takes an iterable or a map as an argument. In your case, `val for key,val in test_list` is an iterable. You fetch values from `test_list` and feed them to `Counter`.
- You don't need the `key, val` semantics, it is confusing in this context, as it suggests you are looping through a dictionary. Instead, you are looping through a list of tuples so `freq_2ndEle=Counter(tp[1] for tp in test_list)` is much clearer - here you access the second tuple element, indexed with `1`.
- `Counter` gives you number of occurrences of each of the second tuple elements. If you print `freq_2ndEle`, you will see this:
  `Counter({7: 3, 5: 2, 8: 1})`, which is a pair of how many times each second element appears in the list.
- In the last step you're sorting the original list by the frequency of the second element using [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted),

  `res=sorted(test_list,key=lambda ele:freq_2ndEle[ele[1]],reverse=True)`
- So you take in `test_list` as an argument to sort, and then you specify the `key` by which you want to sort: in your case the key is the the time second tuple element occurred.
- `freq_2ndEle` stores key-value pairs of second second element name:times it ocurred in `test_list` - it is a dictionary in a way, so you access it as you would access a dictionary, that is - you get the value that corresponds to `ele[1]` which is the (name) of the second tuple element. Name is not the base term, but I thought it may be clearer. The value you fetch with `freq_2ndEle[ele[1]]` is exactly the time `ele[1]` occurred in `test_list`
- Lastly, you sort the keys, but in reverse order - that is, descending, highest to lowest, `[(2, 7), (8, 7), (3, 7), (6, 5), (2, 5), (9, 8)]` with the values that have the same keys (like 7 and 5) grouped together. Note, according to the documentation `sorted` is stable, meaning it will preserve the order of elements from input, and this is why when the keys are the same, you get them in the order as in `test_list` i.e. (2,7) goes first and (3,7) last in the "7" group.

Answer (score 0):

`freq_2ndEle` is a dictionary that contains **the second elements of the tuple** as keys, and **their frequencies** as values. Passing this frequency as a return value of `lambda` in the key argument of the function `sorted` will sort the list by this return value of lambda (which is the frequency).

If your question is about how lambda works, you can refer to this brief [explanation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) which is pretty simple.